# How to view all variable bindings in an open SML session?

Tags: global-variables, sml, smlnj

I was wondering if there is an SML command for viewing all variable bindings in the terminal of an open SML session (something analogous to the

```
dir()
```

command in Python or

```
whos
```

command in MATLAB) ?

Comment: I don't know that such command exists in SML/NJ or in any other SML interactive REPL.